# running Azure function - do I get charged if not used?

Tags: azure

If I run Azure Functions but don't use them (consumption plan), do I get charged for them in any way?

Including if I have some files uploaded on blob storage.

Comment: You also could select a free app service plan, please refer to this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/app-service/).

Comment: I need autoscaling. What is the difference between app service plan and consumption plan?

Comment: Hi, you could check this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale).

Comment: If you want autoscaling, you could select consumption plan.

Comment: Thanks, some questions: 1. Can I switch between consumption to app service plan and vice versa at any moment? I want some initial period of time to have the function running continuously but then on a 'on demand' basis. 2. Also, pricing for app service plan states maximum number of instances limits but I could not find that information about the consumption plan. 3. In order to enable autoscaling do I need to configure anything or does it happen automatically?

Comment: If possible, could you ask a new question? In comment, it is hard to answer your 3 question.

Comment: For question 3. `The Consumption plan automatically allocates compute power when your code is running, scales out as necessary to handle load, and then scales down when code is not running. ` So, you don't need configure anything.

Comment: For question 1, after the web app is created, you could not change consumption plan to app service plan.

Comment: For question 2, `When you're using a Consumption plan, instances of the Azure Functions host are dynamically added and removed based on the number of incoming events. This plan scales automatically, and you are charged for compute resources only when your functions are running. On a Consumption plan, a function can run for a maximum of 10 minutes.` Please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale).

Comment: For question 2, I search much time, it seems official document does not provide maximum instances.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because billing questions should be asked of the vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Functions consumption plan is billed based on per-second resource consumption and executions. **Consumption plan pricing includes a monthly free grant of 1 million requests and 400,000 GB-s of resource consumption per month.**

More information about this please refer to [Function pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/functions/).

According to your description, if you don't use them, you don't get charged for them.

You don't need pay for consumption plan, but you need pay for storage account when you upload files to blob storage. Please refer to this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/blobs/).